# URL Conflict between custom post type, page and post

Tags: wordpress

I created a custom post type 'abcd',when I create a corresponding post "test", url says

```
 mysite.com/abcd/test/
```

Now I created a page which will display all custom posts of type 'abcd'. I need the url of this page to look like

```
 mysite.com/abcd
```

How to do so?

Also lets say i create a post with similar url mysite.com/abcd, Now when i try to open this url, technically what should be displayed?

Answer (score 0):

This is quickly going to become a nightmare of rewrite rules. I'd suggest re-thinking your approach here. I'm working on something similar right now, and what I've done is this:

- Created a custom post type called Games (set singular to game)
- Created a page called Schedule, and made a template that is essentially an archive of the Games post type
- Set Schedule URL to /schedule/, and game schedule to /game/

So now if a user wants to view the schedule, they go /schedule/ and see a list of games. If they click a game, the URL will look something like /game/month-day-opponentCity-opponentTeam/

Comment: Yeah, this is exactly my current approach! I was just wondering if what i have asked is possible.

Any Comments on the second part of question:
`Also lets say i create a post with similar url mysite.com/abcd, Now when i try to open this url, technically what should be displayed?`